# Cron expression for two different time slot?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, cron

How can I parameters running of a script in two different time slot, for example: every 10 minutes from **10:30** to **14:30** AND from **20:00** to **23:40**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the document of Quartz, you should separate jobs.

See [Tutorial 6](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html)

> Note that some scheduling requirements are too complicated to express
>   with a single trigger - such as “every 5 minutes between 9:00 am and
>   10:00 am, and every 20 minutes between 1:00 pm and 10:00 pm”. The
>   solution in this scenario is to simply create two triggers, and
>   register both of them to run the same job.

And see the below scheduler, I haven't used the class but probably useful for you.

[Javadoc DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder.html)

Comment: Hello,
thx for your response, i use separate job for every time slot frequency